# Finding the coefficients to a 4th order linear homogeneous ODE

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to find the coefficients for the gen. solution of a 4th order linear homogeneous ODE.

The ODE is

$ w^{''''} + 4\beta^4 w = 0 $,

and the general solution is

$w(x) = e^{\beta x} [c_1 cos(\beta x) + c_2 sin(\beta x)] + e^{-\beta x} [c_3 cos(\beta x) + c_4 sin(\beta x)] $.

My boundary conditions are:

BC1 $w(0)=0$,
BC2 $w'(0)=0$,
BC3 $w'(l)=0$ and
BC4 $EIw'''(l) = -V $.

BC1 gives $c_1=-c_3$    (1).

Differentiating the gen. solution gives

$w'(x) = e^{\beta x} [-c_1 \beta sin(\beta x) + c_2 \beta cos(\beta x)] + \beta e^{\beta x} [c_1 cos(\beta x) + c_2 sin(\beta x)] + e^{-\beta x} [-c_3 \beta sin(\beta x) + c_4 \beta cos(\beta x)] -\beta e^{-\beta x} [c_3 cos(\beta x) + c_4 sin(\beta x)] $.

Substituting (1) into the above equation leads to

$w'(x) = e^{\beta x} [-c_1 \beta sin(\beta x) + c_2 \beta cos(\beta x)] + \beta e^{\beta x} [c_1 cos(\beta x) + c_2 sin(\beta x)] + e^{-\beta x} [c_1 \beta sin(\beta x) + c_4 \beta cos(\beta x)] -\beta e^{-\beta x} [-c_1 cos(\beta x) + c_4 sin(\beta x)] $.

BC2 gives us $2c_1 + c_2 + c_4 = 0$.

If I plug this into $w'(x)$ I get

$w'(x) = c_1 \beta e^{\beta x} h(x) + c_2 \beta e^{\beta x} g(x) + c_1 \beta e^{-\beta x} g(x) - c_1 \beta e^{-\beta x} h(x) - c_2 \beta e^{-\beta x} h(x)$,

where

$h(x) = cos(\beta x) - sin(\beta x) $,
$g(x) = cos(\beta x) + sin(\beta x) $.

Differentiating 2 more times leads to an expression for the BC4, which does not produce any simple value for $c_1$ or $c_2$.

Is there another simpler way to find the constants?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coefficients can be solved by solving the linear system

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 \beta  & \beta  & -\beta  & \beta  \\
 \beta  e^{\beta  l} (\cos (\beta  l)-\sin (\beta  l)) & \beta  e^{\beta  l} (\sin (\beta  l)+\cos (\beta  l)) & -\beta  e^{-\beta  l} (\sin (\beta  l)+\cos
   (\beta  l)) & \beta  e^{-\beta  l} (\cos (\beta  l)-\sin (\beta  l)) \\
 -2 \beta ^3 EI e^{\beta  l} (\sin (\beta  l)+\cos (\beta  l)) & 2 \beta ^3 EIe^{\beta  l} (\cos (\beta  l)-\sin (\beta  l)) & 2 \beta ^3
   EI e^{-\beta  l} (\cos (\beta  l)-\sin (\beta  l)) & 2 \beta ^3 EI e^{-\beta  l} (\sin (\beta  l)+\cos (\beta  l)) \\
\end{array}
\right)\left(
\begin{array}{c}
c_1\\
c_2\\
c_3\\
c_4
\end{array}
\right) = \left(
\begin{array}{c}
0\\
0\\
0\\
-V
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

and making the substitutions

$$
\cases{
u = \cos(\beta l)-\sin(\beta l)\\
w = \cos(\beta l)-\sin(\beta l)
}
$$

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 1  & 1  & -1  & 1  \\
 u e^{\beta  l} & w e^{\beta  l} & -w e^{-\beta  l} & u e^{-\beta  l} \\
 - w e^{\beta  l} &  u e^{\beta  l} &  u e^{-\beta  l} &  w e^{-\beta  l} \\
\end{array}
\right)\left(
\begin{array}{c}
c_1\\
c_2\\
c_3\\
c_4
\end{array}
\right) = \left(
\begin{array}{c}
0\\
0\\
0\\
-\frac{V}{2\beta^3 EI}
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Comment: Could you please elaborate on that? I am not sure if I can solve this 4x4 matrix by hand.

Comment: Either I ma doing something wrong, or it just does not work out, but I get the following $\frac{V}{2 \beta EI} = 2 c_1 sin(\beta l) (e^{\beta l} - e^{-\beta l}) - c_2 e^{\beta l } (sin(\beta l)+ cos(\beta l))$, which does not help me isolate $c_1$ or $c_2$.

Comment: Please. See some additional simplifications.